# Turning Fast Startup/Hiberboot off causes PC to stay on after shutdown

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, dell-vostro, win10-fast-startup

Fast Startup has been a cause of issues for our company, so we decided to turn it off by setting `HiberbootEnabled` to `0` in registry.
That has caused one single PC (out of around 50 so far, this is being done in stages) to stay on after shutdown. The screen is off, but the PC is clearly running. Setting `HiberbootEnabled` back to `1` fixes the issue instantly.

Fixes I've tried so far (some of them very far off but it's getting desperate):

- turning fastboot off manually in cpl instead (does the same thing but worth a try)
- turning `PowerDownAfterShutdown` to `1` in registry
- resetting CMOS
- resetting BIOS to default and then tinkering with everything power related (including stuff like WoL, really everything i could
- unchecking power related boxes in device manager for USB, network cards and everything else that had the setting avaliable (`allow this device to wake pc` and the other ones)
- unplugging all USB devices before the PC turns off
- uninstalling the network card, graphics card and display drivers

Additional information:

- PC model is Dell Vostro 3681 desktop
- we have many of those at my workplace, they all work as intended after changing the setting
- it's the only PC we've tried it on that has wireless dongles for Logitech mouse/keyboard and a different (newer) ultrawide display (in other words, different peripherals than other workstations)
- probably irrelevant but the mouse/kb combo is Logi MX master 3 and Logi MX keys, both using the Logi receiver
- keeping fastboot on is not an option for reasons I will not be going into

Thank you in advance

Edit 1: we have identified the same issue with another Vostro 3681, this time it's one of the very few PCs we have (and the only one from the tested pool) that still has a USB printer. This is slowly making me think that it actually might be a USB related issue. Seems like too much to be a coincidence. However, I still have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel very silly right now, but it was the bios version. I got told by support that it was up to date and didnt bother to check. The issue is gone after updating bios